# Are there common reasons why Cucumber tests fail 60% of the time on otherwise passing functional code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

I recently started working on a project that has all passing cucumber tests. But I would say 60% of the time they fail on Timeouts, or just all together random intermittent errors. So roughly 1/4 times everything will pass and be green.

Are there common reasons for this sort of intermittence? Should I be concerned?

Comment: I share this poor experience, you'll have to play with timeout delay etc etc. Much tedious work

Answer (score 2):

Acceptance tests may be something tricky on most of time.
You gotta check the async part of your code (Long database transactions, Ajax, MessageQueues). Put some timeout that makes sense for you, for the tests and for the build time (a long build time is not pretty good. I think that 10 minutes is *acceptable*, more than that, you can review your tests, if they are good enough).

Other problem is browser (if you're using it), it can take a lot of time to *warm-up* and start all tests.